# Using useState for storing components as array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

after clicking on button I want add new line into form.
I created and imported Lines component and now after clicking on button I want add 1 into form.

I was able wrote this. But this doesnt work, it will not even show error. and I have no idea how to fix it.

useState is empty array, and after clicking button I wanna add and store new  component.

Thank you

```
const Form = () => {
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);

  const addLine = () => {
    setLines(lines => [...lines, <Lines />]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {lines.map(line => {
          {line}
        })}
      </form>
      <button onClick={addLine}>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> {lines.map(line => {
>   {line}
> })}
> ```

It's not working because you have no return statement in your `map` function. You would write this as:

```
{lines.map(line => {
  return line
})}
```

And since at that point the map function isn't changing anything, you can just use the original array.

```
{lines}
```

But i would urge you not to store elements in react state. You don't have any props in the current example, but as soon as you do it will become extremely easy to have bugs caused by stale props.

Instead, your state should be the minimum amount of data needed to describe the page, and then the elements should be created during render. For example, If each line has some data associated, continue to use an array but just store the data not the elements:

```
const Form = () => {
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);

  const addLine = (name) => {
    setLines(lines => [...lines, { name }]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {lines.map(line => {
          return <Lines name={line.name} />
        })}
      </form>
      <button onClick={addLine}>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or if there's no data about each one, then you could change the state to be just a number:

```
const [numLines, setNumLines] = useState(0);

const addLine = () => {
  setNumLines((prev) => prev + 1);
};

const lines = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
  lines.push(<Lines />);
}

return (
  <div>
    <form>{lines}</form>
    <button onClick={addLine}></button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you. So basically return just "fixed" it.. Can I ask why? How I know when I need to use return in .map and when I dont need to? In my first project I used .map like this and it worked fine

{contactList.map((contact) => (
          <Card contact={contact} key={contact.uid} />
        ))}

Comment: Javascript arrow functions allow a shorthand where you leave out the curly brackets for the function body. When you do this, your function can only have one statement, but a `return` is implied. If have curly brackets, then you doing the long hand version. You can have as many statements as you want, but you need to write the return explicitly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#description

Comment: So both of these would do the same thing`line => { return line }` or `line => line` And your example with the `<Card>` is another case of using the arrow function shorthand .